# Elasticsearch sort by date only of datetime

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field 'datetime' with value like '2014-07-17T01:20:20', on my query I want to sort it by just date like (2014-07-17). Is it possible to sort this way in elasticsearch?

I want to have something like this in database query:
order by DATE(datetime) DESC, name ASC

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just sort on the exact indexed field of datetime ?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to do it. The only possible solution I see for your case is add another field with time set to 00:00:00 and you will be able to achieve what you want.

Comment: @dark_shadow, because I have two criteria for sorting. Like in my example, I need to sort by date and name. vaidik, thanks for the idea, it's one way to do it.

Comment: Found a solution using "_script" and MutableDateTime. Here's my code:    
 "_script" : {
            "script" : "doc[\'date\'].date.dayOfYear",
            "type" : "number",
            "reverse" : true
        }

Comment: @rap, I'm hitting on a public service and I'm pretty sure that scripting is not enabled, however I need the exact behavior as you described. Any recommendations now that (I assume) you have more experience on this topic?